# Javascript check a radio button in form based on a text box value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which inserts and retrieves data from a google sheet.

Example:

I have two radio buttons on my form

```
<input id="Rdio_1" name="RdioSelect" type="radio" class="FirstCheck" 
    value="1" onchange="RadioValInsert ()"/>

<input id="Rdio_2" name="RdioSelect"  type="radio" class="FirstCheck" 
    value="2" onchange="RadioValInsert ()" />
```

when the above is clicked the value of the radio button is stored in a text box..the `RadioValInsert ()` does it

```
<input type="text" id="DatafromRadio" name="DatafromRadio">
```

I am able to insert this value of 1 or 2 into the corresponding cell in google sheet.

When I want to EDIT it, I retrieve the data and the Textbox value is  1 or 2

The button which retrieves the data has a function to check the corresponding radio button based on the value of the Text box.

```
function RadioChk() {
  var val = document.getElementById("DatafromRadio").value;
  if (val == 1) {
    document.getElementById("Rdio_1").checked = true;
  }
  if (val == 2) {
    document.getElementById("Rdio_2").checked = true;
  }
}
```

This is not working

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Post your HTML also

Comment: Please provide your code in JsFiddle , for solve issue and more explanation

Comment: @shivani jsfiddles can be a nice addition, but since SO has also a code snippet tool, that one should be preferred over an external snippet tool

Answer (score 0):

You are doing your `check` and `uncheck` related code inside `RadioChk` function however you haven't bind `click event` on radio inputs . If i correctly understood your question , here is how you can select and deselect your radio buttons.

```js
function RadioValInsert() {
console.log('checked');
  var val =  document.getElementById("DatafromRadio").value;
  if(val ==1 || val ==2){
     uncheckAll();
     document.getElementById("Rdio_"+val).checked = true; 
  }else{
     uncheckAll();
     console.log('choose only between 1 or 2');
  }
  
}

function uncheckAll(){
let ele = document.getElementsByName("RdioSelect");
    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
      ele[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="Rdio_1" name="RdioSelect" type="radio" class="FirstCheck" 
    value="1" onchange="RadioValInsert ()"/>

    <input id="Rdio_2" name="RdioSelect"  type="radio" class="FirstCheck" 
    value="2" onchange="RadioValInsert ()" />
    
    <input type="text" id="DatafromRadio" name="DatafromRadio">
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for that -I can do that and get the value-what i want is the reverse- the text box gets populated by either 1 or 2

Comment: the text box gets populated by either 1 or 2 when data is retrieved from google sheet ...I now need to check the Rdio_1 if text box value is 1 oR check Rdio_2 if value of text box is 2...for this i have the function RadioCheck() given in the original post which is run when button to retrieve data is clicked...Note:This is a static html form .

Answer (score 0):

Try this example where radio selection and textbox value changes as per selection/input

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(dce) {
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[name="RdioSelect"]');
  var textbx = document.querySelector('[name="DatafromRadio"]');

  radios.forEach(function(r) {
    r.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      textbx.value = this.value;
    });
  });

  textbx.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    radios.forEach(function(r) {
      r.checked = (r.value === textbx.value);
    });
  });

  var fillTxt = function(txt) {
    textbx.value = txt;
    textbx.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); //<-- trigger event
  };

  fillTxt('2'); //<--- update text box
});
```

```html
<input id="Rdio_1" name="RdioSelect" type="radio" value="1" />
<input id="Rdio_2" name="RdioSelect" type="radio" value="2" />
<input type="text" id="DatafromRadio" name="DatafromRadio" />
```

> this works only if data is input physically in the text box - in my case the data is retrieved via a function and it populates the text box

In that, just trigger event on textbox

Comment: Hi-Tx for that- this works only if data is input physically in the text box - in my case the data is retrieved via a function and it populates the text box - I guess what i need is to run the function after update of the text box -since it appears that the function to check the radio button is running before the text box is populated.... not sure how to go about that